# Is it possible to make it appear to the target server that incoming requests are from different computers or IPs

Tags: jmeter

I am working on executing a performance script for 250 users. JMeter script is being executed for all the 250 users on the same machine. Some transactions are failing while some are taking longer than expected to execute. So as per the analysis of support team all the 250 threads are hitting the same node of the target server. They made an observation that as all the requests are coming from the same computer or IP so possibly that could be the reason for all the requests being routed to the same node for all the 250 threads.
They said that the load balancer is not able to distribute the load among different nodes. So they made a suggestion to make it appear to the target server that the requests are coming from different computers or IPs so that the load balancer might distribute the load. My question is that is it even possible and even if it is possible does it make any difference to the current setup that we have ?
My larger question is that just by sending the requests from different IPs will the load balancer distribute the load or is the current setup fine and we possible have an architectural issue with the load balancer.
For sending the requests from different IPs one solution is possibly using a master slave configuration. But can this actually resolve the issue of load balancer not being able to distribute the load ?
And even if we have master slave setup we possibly cannot have 250 slave machines to run the script in order to replicate the real world use case.

Comment: Yes you can. Actually, I'm not familiar `jmeter`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have multiple questions:

1/

> "just by sending the requests from different IPs will the load
> balancer distribute the load"

This is dependent on the load balancer configuration. There are certainly configurations that balance the load based on source IP

2/

> "is it even possible and even if it is possible does it make any
> difference to the current setup that we have"

It is possible but it is really hard to do, depend on your configuration

There are some ideas that comes to mind:

- Can you validate with the LB operator why must the LB be source-IP based. That is not a common configuration. You can also ask them to switch to other load balancing rule for your site / for the purpose of performance testing
- Depends on the type of testing/ JMeter script you are runnng and if the page being tested is public-facing, you can try using Lambda or other function as a service to proxy your request which is cheap, have unlimited processing power and large public IP range. This is what I used to do, using JMeter as a trigger to fire a Lambda which in-turn make requests to my servers (You need to notify the cloud provider before doing this)

Answer (score 1):

1. Try adding a [DNS Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to your test plan and use a custom DNS resolver so each virtual user would resolve the target IP address on its own without relying on DNS caching on JVM or OS level.
2. It's possible to configure JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers to send requests from a different IP address (or [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing))

   [image]

   see [IP Spoofing With JMeter: How to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ip-spoofing-jmeter) for more details
3. You can [run JMeter in distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) so each JMeter slave load generator will send requests from a different physical or virtual machine having its own IP address
4. Check your backend configuration like maximum number of incoming connections or load balancing algorithm, it might be the case there are default artificial limits there